# How to apply ngStyle style on focus state in Angular 9

Tags: css, angular

I have a style that I only want to apply to an element when it's state is 'focus'. Most of the colours for this site come from an API so I'm injecting them in where needed with ngStyle which has worked great up until I only needed one applied when focused into a text box.

```
<div class="form__group__full">
    <input type="text" class="form__field" id="callbackName" [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="e.g. John" 
    [ngStyle]="{'color': brand?.colours.primary, 
                  'border-bottom': '2px solid ' + brand?.colours.secondary, 
                  'border-image:focus': 'linear-gradient(to right, ' + brand?.colours.primary + ', ' + brand?.colours.secondary + ')'}">
    <label for="callbackName" class="form__label">Name</label>
</div>
```

The border-bottom and color properties work fine, but the border-image property was just a stab in the dark to be honest - how can I apply a style dynamically only when the object is in the focus state and without calling a pre-defined class in a stylesheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could introduce a boolean flag (eg. `focus`) in the controller and use it to set the styles. Adjust the `focus` flag based on [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) and [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) events.

Try the following

Controller

```js
export class SampleComponent {
  focus = false;    // <-- default value
  ...
}
```

Template

```html
<div class="form__group__full">
  <input (focus)="focus=true" (blur)="focus=false" type="text" class="form__field" id="callbackName" [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="e.g. John" 
    [ngStyle]="focus ? {'color': brand?.colours.primary, 
                'border-bottom': '2px solid ' + brand?.colours.secondary, 
                'border-image:focus': 'linear-gradient(to right, ' + brand?.colours.primary + ', ' + brand?.colours.secondary + ')'} : ''"
  >
  <label for="callbackName" class="form__label">Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Even better if you can use a Subject like `focus: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false)`

Comment: @SantiBarbat Could you please explain why? Then we'd need to use `async` in the template. It might actually complicate it.

Comment: All the advantages of reactive programming

Comment: @SantiBarbat: Reactive for the sake of reactive isn't a good reason. There are places where observables provide an obvious advantage over synchronous data. This isn't the place to unnecessarily introduce an observable.