# Change Font Color for Angular Material - Tree when on Active

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

How to change font color when on Active and Focused in Angular Material Tree.
I am trying to change font color when it's active and focused. I have attached the
angular material tree code.

```
<mat-tree class="example-tree">
  <mat-tree-node>
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-nested-tree-node>
    <div class="mat-tree-node">
      <button>
        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
          {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
        </mat-icon>
      </button>
        {{node.name}}
     </div>
     <div>
       <ng-container></ng-container>
     </div>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
  </mat-tree>
```

> .mat-nested-tree-node, .mat-tree-node {
> color: #4a4a4a;
> }

Comment: Can you try with below link example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63703831/how-to-apply-ngstyle-style-on-focus-state-in-angular-9

Comment: Is there any way to change it in css?

Comment: try this - https://bitsofco.de/when-do-the-hover-focus-and-active-pseudo-classes-apply/